# Pass database data multiple pages though php

Tags: php, html

I have one main page which list alot of different products. What i want is to be able to click on a product and that products information to be passed to a template item page, so information can be displayed.

```
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) :?>

    <div class="col_1_of_3 span_1_of_3 simpleCart_shelfItem">
       <a href="product.php?id=<? echo $product['ProductID']; ?>">

        <div class="product_image">

            <img src="images/allsupplementsImages/<?php echo $product['ProductImage1'];?>_0001_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
            <!--<a href="" class="button item_add item_1"> </a> -->
            <div class="product_container">

                <div class="cart-left">
                    <p class="title"><?php echo $product['Vendor']; ?> </p>
                    <p class="title"><?php echo $product['ProductName']; ?> </p>
                </div>

                <br>
                <span class="amount item_price"><?php echo $product['ProductPrice']; ?></span></a>
                <br>

                <span>
                    <button class="button item_add item_1 " type="button" onclick="location.href='';"> Add to Cart</button>
                </span>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And in my product.php i have

```
$getproduct = $_GET['id'];
echo "$getproduct";
```

The URL that is displaying is "http://localhost/example/product.php?id=%3C?%20echo%20$product[%27ProductID%27];%20?%3E"

The above is not displaying product id, and how can i also bring up other information about this product. such as $product['price'],['department'].

Comment: You can pass the products ID in the URL (for example through the query string: `product.php?product_id=1`) and then fetch the correct product from the database on the product item page.

Comment: I have attempted to add the id to the url but it is not passing correctly or displaying the correct information. i have edited my code

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $product['ProductID']; ?>">`?

Comment: You're using short open tags `<? echo` (which are disabled as default) instead of `<?php echo` or `<?= `. Also, _"and how can i also bring up other information about this product such as $product['price'],['department']"_ - fetch it from the database? It's impossible for us to give a better answer since we know _nothing_ about your app or database structure.

Comment: <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $product['ProductID']; ?>"> Works

Answer (score 0):

Pass the database value into a $_session variable and serve them across pages and use the session_start() in the header